# Add underscore before capitalized letters

Tags: php, regex, match

How do I add underscore (_) infront of all capitalized letters in a string?

PrintHello would become: Print_Hello

PrintHelloWorld would become: Print_Hello_World

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using `negative lookahead`:

```
$str = 'PrintHelloWorld';
$repl = preg_replace('/(?!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $str);
```

OR using `positive lookahead`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/.(?=[A-Z])/', '$0_', $str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Print_Hello_World
```

**Update:** Even simpler would be to use: (*thanks to @CasimiretHippolyte*)

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\B[A-Z]/', '_$0', $str);
```

- `\B` matches when not at a word boundary

Comment: you can do this `~\B[A-Z]~`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Ah that's right, I always forget using `\B`, let me update

Answer (score 1):

You also had the requirement to ignore the first capital letter, so I put in a "negative look-behind" to check to see if it's at the start of the string or not.  The start of the string is represented by ^.

```
<?php
$string = 'PrintHelloWorld';
$pattern = '/(?<!^)([A-Z])/';
$replacement = '_$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Here's a link to play with the code: http://ideone.com/HvjfWW